# React Native, limit JSON output from external document

Tags: android, json, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to output JSON content into a Flatlist like described in the react native docs. Outputting the content to the page isn't the issue, I'm facing, I'm trying to limit the amount of data which is being output from each JSON field.

For example, there are 4 states, physical, mental, emotional and spiritual. I'm trying to output just the first element, so in this case physical, or [0].

I have the following code which will output all 4 of the values and I'm having trouble limiting the values to the just the first element:

```
<FlatList
data={this.state.dimensionJson}
renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={[styles.dimensionTitle, { color: progress[3] }]}>{item.type}</Text>}
keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
/>
```

the code which retrieves the JSON data is as follows:

```
componentDidMount(){
return fetch(url,{
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'applications/json',
  },
},
)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  this.setState({
    isLoading: false,
    titleData: responseJson.title,
    fullJSON: responseJson,
    dimensionJson: responseJson.dimensions,

  }, function() {



    //Potentially write if function in here for limiting output
  });
})
.catch((error) =>{
  console.error(error)
})}
```

and finally my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "description": "Begin by identifying  the dimension of energy you would like to address. Your scores can guide the way.",
  "title": "Choose a Dimension",
  "dimensions": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "type": "Physical",
      "desc": "Physical energy is the quantity of  energy. This dimension shapes our sustainability and long-term productivity."
     },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "Mental",
       "desc": "Mental energy is the focus of our energy. It influences our 
concentration, control of attention, and the likelihood of making mistakes."
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "Emotional",
      "desc": "Emotional energy is the quality of our energy. It affects how 
resilient we are, especially when faced with complexity."
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "Spiritual",
      "desc": "Spiritual energy is the energy we derive from serving a  
greater purpose. It inspires us and answers the question ‘Why do I get out 
of bed each morning?"
    }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: what does {item.type} output? which state element is holding that json data?

Comment: @soldfor I think you've led me to the cause of the problem, I may need to create an array inside the state which will hold the data and then parse the data like a normal array. Not entirely sure it'll work but I'm going to give it a shot today

Comment: Exactly. When u get your response, store the response in a state. Then, map through that array

Answer (score 0):

Try Slicing the Data

```
 <FlatList
                        data={this.state.dimensionJson.slice(0,1)}
                        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={[styles.dimensionTitle, { color: progress[3] }]}>{item.type}</Text>}
                        keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
                        />
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this doesn't quite work. I tried to implement it on the data but I receive a TypeError: undefined is no an object, I then moved it into the {item.type.slice(0,1)} which essentially has the same output as {item.type[1]}. I'm trying to output the whole word, 'Physical' and nothing else, as opposed to just the first character, my bad

Comment: what does {item.type} output?

Comment: @soldfor it outputs physical, mental, emotional and spiritual. I'd like it to output just physical